# Get name of Block while in Block (self) Ruby

Tags: ruby, block, self, proc

I am wondering how to get the name of a block/proc while in the block that will then be passed to a method. I need the name of a block like so:

```
method("hello") do
  puts "My name is #{self}"
end
```

Which would print out something like when the method runs the block:

```
"My name is #<Proc:0xa3de668@/path/to/file.rb:8>"
```

Comment: Do you really just want the location in the source code of the block? Blocks (and Procs in general) don’t really have names.

Comment: Maybe you can get the name of a proc, but you cannot get the name of a block because block is not a Ruby object.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a reference to the implicitly passed block inside the method yield-ing it, by calling `Proc.new` (inside the method) without supplying a block. For instance:

```
def speak
  puts yield
  block = Proc.new # Creates a proc object from the implictly passed block.
  puts block.call
end

speak { "Hello, from implicit block!" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't do this for blocks, but for procs...

```
def hello
  puts yield
end

my_proc = Proc.new {"I am #{my_proc}"}

method("hello").call(&my_proc)

#I am <#Proc:0x0...@...>
```